# GooglePlay login doesn't work anymore (incorrectly configured)

Tags: android, google-play

after a few weeks of working on my game, google play login doesn't work anymore. When trying to login, I get a message box saying the application is incorrectly configured. I am using the BaseGameUtils classes and cocos2d-x.
I tried the troubleshooting guide from google, didn't help. Credentials, AppID, tester logins, everything is fine and identical on both the apk and developer console. I deleted the ClientID, created new ones, different ones, I even tried a different eclipse version (with a different sha1 debug key).

I am only testing the debug builds right now.

Hoping someone can help or give a hint

Regards
pettersson